# List item Attachments unviewable by last modified

Tags: attachments

I have a SharePoint 2010 list where my customer can access an item for edit.  He can add attachments to the list item.  However, after he saves the list item and re-opens it for view/edit, the attachment is not visible to him.  I can see the attachment, but he cannot.  HELP!

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible reasons for this:

- Unique permissions in Attachments folder

Every list has a folder called Attachments - it will not be visible from UI. You can see it under:
/site/Lists/listname/Attachments 
It is difficult to achieve but maybe you managed. Is it possible that you modified permissions to this folder, assigning it unique permissions and hence the users cannot them?

- Running workflow removing permissions

It is possible to remove permissions after the item has been added with a workflow. Is there any running on your list?

- Content approval issues

For no reason known to me, SP seems to be having issues with attachments when content approval is enabled. Is it the case on your list? Does the issue persist when you disable content approval?

- Unique permissions somewhere else

Call me stubborn but... 
The attachments are clearly there, because you can see them. If your users can't, it looks like a permission issue.
Test it: 
Pick one user, assign him site collection admin -> does he see the attachments now? 
If not: Something has unique permissions and didn't get updated with the admin. Go to Site Settings>>Site permissions>> On a YELLOW ribbon there will be written "Some items have different permissions">>Click on it to see these items>>Remove unique permissions from anything that seems issue-related or post them here

Please also check:
https://pamdegraff.wordpress.com/2011/10/11/sharepoint-list-attachments-disabled/  
[Issue with list attachments when content approval is enabled](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79014/issue-with-list-attachments-when-content-approval-is-enabled?rq=1)

Comment: The web part does not have audience targeting set, so members of all associated permission groups should be able to see the attachments.  Here's another problem.  When the user clicks the hyperlink to view an item, the form is BLANK.  He then clicks the Edit button and the form populates.  From there he can perform edit and uploading of attachments.  Once he saves however, he cannot see nor access the attachment link.

Comment: Does this happen to a list only as a webpart? When you go to the list itself the behaviour is the same or different?

Comment: Behavior is same either way